# iOS transform3D， two view X-axis Rotate， change the view hierarchy，why？

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
    UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    redView.center = CGPointMake(150, 150);
    redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
//    redView.layer.zPosition = -1;
    [self.view addSubview:redView];
    self.redView = redView;
    
    UIView *orangeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    orangeView.center = CGPointMake(150, 150);
    orangeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [self.view addSubview:orangeView];
    self.orangeView = orangeView;
```

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
self.redView.transform3D = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, M_PI_2 / 2, 1, 0, 0);
self.orangeView.transform3D = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, M_PI_2 / 2, 1, 0, 0);
}];

[before transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDEnc.png)

[after transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYUXC.png)

why？please help me， thank you！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the view hierarchy did not change - the code below will proof it. Specifically, I show the hierarchy at the beginning and I've added a completion block to show the hierarchy at the end and it is the same.

However, what you see changed from 2D to 3D and so it looks different to what you expect. The code below will also show that. Rotating the planes around different axis.

[image]

```
    NSLog(@"Red    %p", redView);
    NSLog(@"Orange %p", orangeView );

    NSLog ( @"Hierarchy at start" );

    for ( UIView * view in self.view.subviews )
    {
        NSLog ( @"\t%p", view );
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
             animations: ^ {

        self.redView.transform3D    = CATransform3DRotate ( CATransform3DIdentity, M_PI_2 / 2, 1, 0, 0 );
        self.orangeView.transform3D = CATransform3DRotate ( CATransform3DIdentity, M_PI_2 / 2, 0, 1, 0 );

    }
             completion: ^ ( BOOL finished ) {

        NSLog ( @"Hierarchy at end fin %@", finished ? @"YES" : @"NO" );

        for ( UIView * view in self.view.subviews )
        {
            NSLog ( @"\t%p", view );
        }

    }];
```

Comment: thank you！ I konw the view hierarchy did not change,  but after rotate，It's going to show up at the top of orangeview. why?

Comment: The smaller view is behind, but when you rotate it, because it is smaller, it does not rotate away as far as the bigger one. The bigger one rotates the same angle but, because it is bigger, the distance is further. So before the rotate they are in the same place but because of hierarchy the bigger one is seen. After rotate the smaller one is closer and shows up in front. Yes thank this is a nice one, almost like a puzzle.

Comment: I don't understand，I think the same angle，have nothing to do with size

Comment: Try this as well - for redView, change your code to ```redView.center = CGPointMake( 150, 151 );``` and you will see what you expect.

Comment: He he he this remains a puzzle. Size matters if you rotate each shape around its bottom axis which is what I thought but you are right. Size does not matter if you rotate around the center, but if you move the center e.g. as in my most recent comment then again it is different.

Comment: Not sure how to think about this myself, but it seems size does matter ... If you e.g. add another view with smaller size, say ( 50, 50 ), then it ends up in front. If you add it with a larger size, say ( 90, 90 ) then it enters in between and if with a larger size of say ( 110, 110 ) then it ends up behind all. So, this is anecdotal only, it seems if they occupy the same space then the view hierarchy does not play a role, but the relative size of the object determines which one displays first, with the smaller ones being preferred.

Comment: It should be the iOS system rendering mechanism，like stacking context in css

Comment: Yes I suppose so but just anecdotal, no documentation to back that up ... Been working for years and Apple docs is maybe not the most complete there is.